# How to solve this probability?

Tags: probability

> Each student has blonde hair or wears eyeglasses. $\frac 16$ of students who has a blonde hair wears eyeglasses and $\frac 13$ of the students who wears eyeglasses have blonde hair.
>
> Determine the fraction of the class in total who wears eyeglasses.

I tried to consider it as inclusive probability, but I cant understand how I am supposed to make an intersection between eyeglasses and blonde hair.

Thus, $1-\left(\cfrac 16+\cfrac 13\right)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In your questions, you should show your own work in order to get useful answers.

Comment: can you draw a probability table or a venn diagram? - I was puzzled, however zero students have non-blonde hair or wear no eye glasses - I did it with a table with E, E' B,B'

Comment: Sorry for being unclear here, I was very new with the page didn't expect the integrity of the page. I will improve on my next queries.

Comment: if you use a venn diagram, assume 6 people are in the blonde circle for convenience - how are they spread out between the two parts of the circle? - non are outside both circles - then figure out the second circle

Comment: I don't think it deserves 6 thumbs down, plenty of other questions with no attempts crop up, good luck with future questions!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
& \text{Wearing Glasses} & \text{No Glasses} \\
\hline
\text{Blonde} & O|X & OOOOO \\
\text{No blonde} & XX & - \\
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
& \text{Wearing Glasses} & \text{No Glasses} \\
\hline
\text{Blonde} & O|X=1 & OOOOO|X=5 \\
\text{No blonde} & OO|XX=2 & - \\
\hline
\text{Sum} & 3 & 5\\
\end{array}
$$

$$The\ fraction\ of\ the\ class\ in\ total\ who\ wears\ eyeglasses = \frac{3}{8}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let 'a' be the fraction of students having blonde hair as well as wearing eyeglasses.
$$.$$
And 'b' and 'g' be ratio of blonde hair and wearing eyeglasses respectively.
$$a = \frac{1}{6} b , 
a = \frac{1}{3} g$$
$$
\implies b = 2g
\wedge g = 1 - b + a $$
$$
\implies g = 1- 2g + \frac{1}{3} g$$
$$
\frac{8}{3} g = 1$$
$$
g = 3/8$$
So $\frac{3}{8}$ fraction of class wear eyeglasses

Answer (score 1):

ok, here's a table, I've started off by assuming there ARE 6 blonde students

```
    E    E'
 B  ?    ?    6
 B' ?    ?
```

now 1/6 of students are blonde with eye glasses

```
    E    E'
 B  1    5    6
 B' ?    ?
```

1/3 of students with eyeglasses have blonde hair - so

```
    E    E'
 B  1    5    6
 B' 2    ?
    3
```

no student has no eye glass or non blonde hair

```
    E    E'
 B  1    5    6
 B' 2    0    2 
    3    5
```

so 3 of the eight 'notional' students has eyeglasses

answer 3/8

Answer (score 0):

To set up this problem you start from the fact that each student is either blonde and does not wear eyeglasses, or wears eyeglasses and is not blonde, or wears eyeglasses and is blonde.  Let the fractions of those three types be $b$, $e$, and $t$ respectively; the problem asks to find $e+t$.

We know that all the students fall into one of those categories, and that those categories are mutually exclusive, so
$$
b+e+t = 1
$$
Also, the problem tells you that a sixth of the students that have blonde hare [$\frac16 (b+t)$ ] wears eyeglasses; if such a student does were eyeglasses she is a member of $t$, so
$$
t=\frac16(b+t)
$$
Similarly,
$$
t=\frac13(e+t)$$

So you have three linear equations for $b,e,t$ and solving them is trivial; for example, the second equation becomes $\frac56t = b$ and in the end you get 
$$
b+e+t = 1 \implies \frac56 t + \frac23 t + t =1 \implies t=\frac25
$$
which then gives
$$
b=\frac13\\e=\frac4{15}\\ e+t = \frac23
$$
so the answer is $\frac23$.